# Data vault connect multiple hubs into links, is it the best way using one link, or splitting the links is always a good way in data vault?

Tags: data-vault

I am transforming an existing star schema model into data vault. The main table contains 4 foreign keys coming from 4 different table. In data vault modelling techniques, what is the best practice in modelling such thing:

1. Use one link connecting the 4 tables hashed FK into the main table's hub?
2. Or using 4 links, each one is a relation between the main table and itself?

I am new to data vault and I didn't go through such thing when I learned about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should respect the "unit of work", otherwise, you might create relationship that never existed.

Option one is the one you would want to implement.

Here's some lecture if you want.
https://hanshultgren.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/unit-of-work-demystified/

Comment: so best way is one link connecting hubs altogether.

Comment: not only the best way, but how it should be.